# angularjs pass index through directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need help with this code.

```
<ul ng-init="round = 'round'">
  <li ng-repeat="mesa in mesas" ng-click="selected($index)">
    <div id="{{round}}">&nbsp;</div>
    MESA {{mesa}}
   </li>
 </ul>


$scope.selected = function ($index){
    $scope.index.round = 'round1';
  }
```

I need that only the li that is being clicked to change the css name, but instead it change all of the li's that I have listed.

Comment: What css name are you referring to?

Comment: Stop using `$index` for these kind of problems. If you repeat over an array, you can use the object given by Angular. In your case `selected(mesa)`. Also, you will get a lot of `divs` with the same `id` which is not valid HTML. By the way, your function does not make any sense. Seems like you miss the basic understanding of javascript it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the variable `round` outside of the repeat loop, so the expression `{{round}}` will always point to that singular, shared variable. If you update it once, it updates for all children of the `ng-repeat`.

If I understand your question, you're trying to change the CSS class for the div inside the repeat, correct? What you can do in that case is store the selected index on the controller's scope, and check that value against the index inside the loop

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="mesa in mesas" ng-click="select($index)">
    <div class="round1" ng-if="selectedIndex === $index">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="round" ng-if="selectedIndex !== $index">&nbsp;</div>
    MESA {{mesa}}
  </li>
</ul>


$scope.select = function ($index){
  $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
}
```

You could also use `ng-class` instead of `ng-if` depending on how your CSS is structured, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
     .round {
      background: green;
     }
     .round1 {
      background: blue;
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="controller">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="mesa in mesas" ng-click="selected($index)" ng-class="[index[$index].round]">
            <div id="{{ index[$index].id }}">&nbsp;</div>
            MESA {{ mesa }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('controller', controller);

controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

function controller($scope) {
    $scope.mesas = ['1', '2', '3'];
    $scope.index = [{
        id: '1',
        round: 'round'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        round: 'round'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        round: 'round'
    }];

    $scope.selected = function($index) {
        $scope.index[$index].round = $scope.index[$index].round === 'round' ? 'round1' : 'round';
    }
}
</script>
```

I think is what u looking for¿?